# Implementing Replication and Fault Tolerance in CORBA

Tags: java, replication, corba, fault-tolerance

I want to implement the replication and fault tolerance in CORBA using Java.

I programmed CORBA servers and clients in Java using Java IDL technology .

by looking at the Official docs of Java IDL , i didn't find any thing regarding this (or i am missing something ?)

but i found so many White papers about Replications and Fault tolerance on net.

Is there any Java implementation does this ?
or

I do have to implement this stuff?

Comment: Last I checked Borland Visibroker has alot of this functionality. What vendor solution are you using?

Comment: okay , i look at that .
I am using Java IDL implementation provided itself in JDK

Comment: @Perception Borland Visibroker quite commercial product , 
is there any OSS product exists in this category ?

Comment: Open source, Java compatible ORB's are hard to come by. You can check out JacORB, it's been around for awhile and is very stable.

Comment: @Perception by looking at [features](http://goo.gl/xqj0u) of JacORB . I didn't see any replication / fault tolerance implemented.

Comment: @this-abhi Is the answer sufficient for you or do you have further questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No OSS Java ORB supports CORBA's native fault tolerance or replication by default. There exists a commercial JacORB variant, sold by [PrimTech](http://www.prismtech.com/openfusion/products/openfusion-jacorb). Also [WebLogic](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/applications/crmondemand/index.html) and [WebSphere](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/websphere/) support this.

I see two options for you, if won't buy a commercial product:

1. implement your own FT/Replication functionality
2. let someone else implement the FT/Replication functionality

Comment: Why these features are not provided by default , as they part of CORBA standards right?

Comment: They are part of a CORBA standard, but there is more than one. for RT CORBA see http://staff.iha.dk/jrt/tioomi/05-01-04.pdf

Comment: most OSS implementations only support default CORBA v2.3